# How To Restrict Changing Into Landscape Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I do have five view controllers, and i am  navigating from first view Controller  to end view Controller (fifth view controller)

In middle i do third view i need to do orientation. for landscape and potrait mode.

and from there it need to be potrait mode  only.

I added this delegate method for orientation in fouth viewController . but its not effecting

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    //Support orientation for Portrait 
        return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape)
  return NO;
else
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your changing orientation in your first view.Open your third view and write this method then change whatever you want...i think you should write this in all of the view expect third view...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
         return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Now in your third view write your code....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
//Support orientation for Portrait 
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: My third view do have orientation... Landscape and potrait rest of them do not have any orientation.

Comment: When fouth view loaded in view did load iam setting     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];  its not working for me. any suggest how to implement this stuff

Comment: you can try that in `-(void)viewWillAppear`